# Tracking an external directory by git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

MainApp directory is the main git repository

```
MainApp
|
|
+--Js/MyPlugin/Plugin.js
|
+--Plugins/MyPlugin+-Controller/..
|                  |
|                  +-Model/..
|                  |
|                  +-.git 
|
+--Model/..
+--View/..
+--Controller/..
+--.git
```

`MainApp/Plugins/MyPlugin` directory is a git submodule.
Can I track the `/js/MyPlugin` external directory with MyPlugin git submodule? is there any possible way to make that folder trackable without creating that javascript folder inside of `/MainApp/Plugins/MyPlugin` directory and symlinking?

Comment: I don't see "MainApp/MyPlugin". I see MainApp/Plugins/MyPlugin: is that the submodule?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I made you confuse. I edited the question again.

Comment: You could create a submodule with `/js/MyPlugin`, I guess. But that's not very practical, in any case. Maybe create another "Superproject" which would contain three submodules and some symlinks in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Since a submodule has only one path, if you need to have part of it elsewhare in your repo:

- either MyPlugin is not a good candidate for a git submodule
- or your symlink solution remains the best alternative workaround.
  (Except you don't have to create the `Js` folder inside the submodule, you could create `Js/MyPlugin/` and symlink only the content: `Plugin.js`)

Comment: It's unclear where the symlink and the plugin.js is actually stored. If you were to clone this submodule in new parent parent project, what is actually cloned?  Does it only clone the Plugin.js and you're responsible for creating the Js/MyPlugin/ and the symlink?  If so, Githas some glaring and overlooked issues that makes it unsuitable for modular development.

Comment: @ATL_DEV A symlink within the same repo would work though.

Comment: Interesting, but still makes my brain hurt.  The problem with Git (and UNIX in general) is that its concepts only make sense if you think about its implementation, which is like forcing a driver to know about how their engine and transmission works in order to drive.

Comment: @ATL_DEV You don't: you can read that parable instead: http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I will read it carefully.  It's been years now and everytime I encounter Git, I feel like I am relearning it all over again.  It's akin to learning about electricity.  It doesn't click and then it clicks and then you think some more about it and then it unclicks.  The process repeats itself all over again. I notice many people often resort to math like Ohms Law and Kirchhoff's equation, but I wonder if they really understand it intuitively.